# Why does R function print.xtableFtable ignore my options?

Tags: r, latex, output

I am having the following code and print.xtableFtable ignores the additional options for latex.

```
##### Contingency tables - 34Y
library(xtable)
B <- ftable(prereg34Y_sub$employmentStatus34Y, prereg34Y_sub$ethnicity34Y, dnn=c("Unemployed", "NonBritish"))
sink("CTFemaleNonBrit34Y.tex", type="output")
print.xtableFtable(xtableFtable(B, method = "compact"), table.placement = "h!")
sink()
```

The output is:

```
% latex table generated in R 3.3.1 by xtable 1.8-2 package
% Sat Oct 22 18:08:35 2016
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l |rr}
\hline
Unemployed $\vert$ NonBritish & \multicolumn{1}{l}{    0} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{    1} \\ 
\hline
0                              & 2065 &   68 \\ 
1                              &   31 &    2 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The position of the table is ht instead of h!. Does anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem that the `table.placement` argument gets passed along from `print.xtableFtable` to `print.xtable`, but you can set the optionally globally `options(xtable.table.placement = "h!")` before running `print(xtableFtable(B))`

Example

```
library(xtable)

# table.placement doesnt seem to work
B <- ftable(mtcars$am, mtcars$cyl, dnn=c("Unemployed", "NonBritish"))
print(xtableFtable(B), table.placement = "h!")     
# % latex table generated in R 3.3.1 by xtable 1.8-2 package
# % Sat Oct 22 18:00:52 2016
# \begin{table}[ht]
# ---
# ---

# But works for other data types
B2 <- table(mtcars$am, mtcars$cyl, dnn=c("Unemployed", "NonBritish"))
print(xtable(B2), table.placement = "h!")
# % latex table generated in R 3.3.1 by xtable 1.8-2 package
# % Sat Oct 22 18:00:52 2016
# \begin{table}[h!]
# ---
# ---
```

So set options globally

```
options(xtable.table.placement = "h!")
print(xtableFtable(B))
# % latex table generated in R 3.3.1 by xtable 1.8-2 package
# % Sat Oct 22 18:00:52 2016
# \begin{table}[h!]
# ---
# ---
```

Comment: It works now. I've learnt something new today: Setting options globally.