# Inconsistent options when printing tables with xtable - ftable - knitr

Tags: r, knitr, xtable

I have some multidimensional data (survey data: some people answering questions about each other) and I want to output a latex table using knitr. Everything works as expected, except that the table is quite long and so I want to use the formatting option `longtable` to automatically break the table at the bottom of the page and continue on the next. This is for some reason not working, the option is ignored: the code outputs a "tex table" but in the default "table" format. Other options are not ignored, however (e.g. `rotate.colnames`).

I first make a `ftable` and convert this to an xtable using `xtableFtable` (part of the package `xtable`). Then I use the `print.xtableFtable` function to output the actual table in latex formatting.

Referencing the documentation on [print.xtableFtable](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xtable/versions/1.8-2/topics/xtableFtablehttp://), I then use the option `tabular.environment = getOption("xtable.tabular.environment", "longtable")`. However, this option is ignored (also no error or warning message) and a "normal" table is printed. Using the short form `tabular.environment = "longtable"` also is ignored.

Weird thing is, the option `rotate.colnames = TRUE` is not ignored, but I don't understand why. It might have to do with the `xtableFtable` function because a normal 2-dimensional table is printed with the "longtable" option, but I don't know exactly.

```
# sample data - 3 people asked how often they agree with the others
dat <- data.frame("interviewee" = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), "subject" = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2), "answer" = c("agrees", "agrees", "agrees", "disagrees", "disagrees", "disagrees", "agrees", "agrees", "disagrees", "disagrees", "disagrees", "agrees"))

# using ftable to see frequencies how often people agree and disagree with each other
# (this is also how I would like the latex table to look)
f.dat <- ftable(dat$interviewee, dat$answer, dat$subject)

# converting to xtable 
x.f.table <- xtableFtable(f.dat)

# printing to .tex format
print.xtableFtable(x.f.table)

# previous line works as expected, except that the table is spanning multiple pages so I want to use the option "longtable" 
# the next lines don't work (as in, the environment option is ignored)
print.xtableFtable(x.f.table, tabular.environment = getOption("xtable.tabular.environment", "longtable"))
print.xtableFtable(x.f.table, tabular.environment = "longtable") 

# this however does work: the column names are rotated
print.xtableFtable(x.f.table, rotate.colnames = TRUE)

# using a normal table, so without ftable, gives output using the option longtable
simple.table = table(dat$interviewee, dat$answers)
print(simple.table, tabular.environment = "longtable")
```

I would very much welcome any suggestions, solutions or otherwise ways to make this work

Comment: [maybe relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40194390/why-does-r-function-print-xtableftable-ignore-my-options/40194791#40194791) - so try setting the option globally

Comment: I'm not an expert, but the examples of `longtable`s that I found look like it is instead of both the `table` and `tabular` environments, so you might need to deal with that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really **the** answer as to why the function ignores some of the options but thanks to [user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650) pointing me to an earlier question/answer suggesting to set global options instead of passing it in the function.

This does work now:

```
# first set the global options
options(xtable.tabular.environment = "longtable")

# continuing with the data from the question
print.xtableFtable(x.f.table)
```

(for some reason the option `rotate.columns = TRUE` now gives an error when compiling the tex code but that is another issue altogether)